# Alternating row colors with CSS will not work inside another

Tags: css

Why is this? Both blockquotes are blue. The TR's do alternate in color, but the blockquotes will not. How come?

```
<tr>
    <blockquote>Hello</blockquote>
</tr>

<tr>
    <blockquote>Hello</blockquote>
</tr>



tr:nth-child(even){ background-color: #272727; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #222222; }

blockquote:nth-child(even){ background-color: red; }
blockquote:nth-child(odd) { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: For starters that HTML is invalid.

Comment: Put the `blockquote` tags in `td` tags. Secondly, the blockquotes aren't children in the same tag (but two blockquotes in one td and see if it works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nth-of-type` instead:

```
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #272727;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #222222;
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) blockquote {
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) blockquote {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ebCwM/)** (colors changed for visibility)

Comment: Yes that did it, you can also go by the same way you had it here just need to have tr be the main parent: http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/387RZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Both block quotes are the 1st element of their respective parents, which is odd... Therefore:
blockquote:nth-child(odd) is true.